# How to Add Lore while Engaing the Senses to my Narritive?

Tags: lore, narration

How do I engage my player's senses as a GM, so as to provide an immersive experience for my players, without going into too much detail?

How do I add a sense of lore to my world during prep, and during the actual game itself?  Do I need to answer

Who
What
When
Why
Were
How

If so, can you provide me with some examples please?  Thank you for your time.

Comment: This is the kind of question people can (and do) write entire books about. If you can, try to ask a more specific question, or perhaps you can ask for good sources where you can learn how to do immersive storytelling.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Giving a setting a feeling of ancientness](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/21709/giving-a-setting-a-feeling-of-ancientness), and see also [What are the key considerations to creating compelling environments?](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/23076/4398)

Comment: Can you tell us what sort of resources you have for your game?  Do you have locations, but need lore?  Do you have lore, but need to plant it in the world?  Do you have neither?  Both?