# How can I publish/market an RPG I have created?

Tags: publishing

I have developed a rpg game and I would like to market it but not sure how to do so.
I am not trying to make a mint off the game more for the fun of making the game.
I would like to market it on the internet just don't know how.

Comment: Just to be sure you're in the right place, you're talking about a paper & pencil roleplaying game like Dungeons & Dragons, not a video game, right?

Comment: This feels... overbroad to really be answerable. The short answer is "Make a website, share it on enthusiast forums that encourage that sort of thing (StackExchange is not one of them)", but the long answer is *several* orders of magnitude longer, and is going to be tied to all sorts of details you haven't provided (target audience, marketing budget, expectation of *any* profit or just fan published for fun, etc.).

Comment: Is there a more specific part of the process we can immediately help you with? What are options you've considered or are viable for you? Which ones aren't? Are you familiar with the sites Indie devs generally use? Do you know how to make a PDF? We need to know the parts you don't know.

Comment: Related, dupe?: [How would I go about publishing the RPGs I've created?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/16414)